# CSS Header Fixed Position

Tags: html, css

I have a site that horizontally scrolls across five page widths.  I want the header to stay fixed in the same position while the pages scroll horizontally.  In Safari, the header stays with the css rule, "position:fixed".  In Firefox, Chrome and IE, however, the header scrolls with the pages.  Is there an easier way than pulling the header out of the wrapper for each page?  The code is complicated so I want to avoid pulling it outside.

```
<div id="page1">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="page3">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    background-color: rgba(43, 77, 105, .6);
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
   top:0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting left:0  ? may be useful

Comment: It's working for me on firefox with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oc8ywqg3/

Comment: @PravinVaichal That did it.  Put it in as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Comment: Instead of using width, try using: `left: 0; right: 0;` (wild guess).

Comment: @TheHawk, if you are having a fixed header like that, then you only need one rather than one for each page (and you may want to move it out of the page div)

Comment: from your ex.: why do you repeat div class header ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `left:0` property for `.header` class to fix the issue

Happy Coding :)